# Why is error undefined in my Axios catch?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm using Vue.JS on the front end, Laravel on the backend, and Axios to post some form data, my axios method is set up like below:

```
axios
    .post("/api/xxxxx", formData)

    .then(function(response) {
        console.log('inside then');
        console.log(response.data);
        self.errorMessage = response.data.data.message;

    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log('inside catch');
        console.log(error);
        self.errorMessage = error.response.data.message;

    });
},
```

Everything works as expected within the '**then**' block, but when I clear my cookies and cache and resubmitting, the code in the **catch** block is triggered however this time no error message is displayed on the front end (using errorMessage).

When I check Vue Dev tools, I can see `**Error: Unexpected end of JSON input**.`

And in my console: `Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`

So I guess the error here is showing up as undefined.

What I want is for my **errorMessage** to contain the message from the response whenever there is an error.

When I check my network tab and preview the response, I do see data.message containing the relevant text: ("Something's gone wrong") But I'm not sure why I can't get this to display when the code in the catch block is triggered.

Comment: did you try to check application content type on response. Seems like issue with data. It is not json string format.

Comment: Yes, content-type is 'application/json'

Comment: are you sure that you need error.data.data.message and not error.data.message ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Even when I log 'error' on its own it's showing up with the errors mentioned in the question.

Comment: it's `error.response.data.data.message`

Comment: You're correct there @Ohgodwhy, but my error itself is still showing undefined even though a response exists.

Comment: the error cannot be any clearer: apparently `error.response` is undefined.

Comment: @Flame but the response exists, and I can see it in the network tab so why is error undefined in catch?

Comment: log `error.response`, if its not undefined then youre looking at the wrong line of code.

Comment: `**Error: Unexpected end of JSON input**.` sounds to me a bit like it's not json. What exactly is the error response in network tab?

Comment: @AJT82 the response is {"success":false,"win":false,"data":{"message":"This has already been entered by another user. ","refresh":false}}

Comment: then `error.response.data.data.message` should surely be the correct piece of code and shouldn't produce errors. So are you now getting the `errorMessage` correctly and still throwing errors?

Comment: That’s correct I’m still getting the error @AJT82